# Accessing JSON object in multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to use one json object in multiple pages.I m creating on javascript file and

`SampleJson.js`

and referring in all pages in my application.Inside the javascript file i m creating a JSON object.And i will store values into the json object.I want to use the stored values in all my pages.Is that possible to use like this? Please suggest for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just assign your JSON object to a variable in SampleJson.js

`var SOME_UNIQUE_NAME = {...}`

Then reference it throughout your app like `SOME_UNIQUE_NAME.key_name`

Comment: In addition, you should also get acquainted with HTML5 LocalStorage/SessionStorage/IndexedDB: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: @Rob M. If I m creating json object statically then it is working fine throughout the app.but Dynamically i m giving it is not working.how to save dynamically json object?

Comment: There isn't really a need to "save it". It may be better to just do an AJAX request to the script that generates the JSON and run the response through the javascript JSON.parse method. If you don't want to keep reprocessing on the server-side use caching.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the Json object as a cookie.  Here is the code in jQuery using the cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
$.cookie('NAME', JSON.stringify(<JSON OBJECT>));
```

and then when you want to access the JSON object:

$.parseJSON($.cookie('NAME'));

You can also do this with simple javascript and not the jQuery plugin.  The plugin makes the code much more elegant.